# force a page refresh from code behind inside the ajax file upload control event

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using Ajax File Upload to insert some images into my database and also i am using a data-list to display those images.

> `<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" Height="141px" Width="640px" MaximumNumberOfFiles="100" OnUploadStart="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadStart" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" OnUploadCompleteAll="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadCompleteAll" />`

and the data-list

> `<asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" CellPadding="5">
>   <ItemTemplate>
>   <a id="imageLink" href='<%# Eval("ImageName","~/SlideImages/{0}") %>' title='<%#Eval("Description") %>' rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" runat="server" >
>   <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageName", "~/SlideImages/{0}") %>' runat="server" Width="112" Height="84" />
>   </a>
>   </ItemTemplate>
>   <ItemStyle BorderColor="Brown" BorderStyle="dotted" BorderWidth="3px" HorizontalAlign="Center"
>   VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
>   </asp:DataList>`

and the code behind as follows :-

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindDataList();
    }
}
protected void BindDataList()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ImageName,Description from SlideShowTable", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dlImages.DataSource = dt;
    dlImages.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
 protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
    string filePath = "~/SlideImages/";
    AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.FileName)));
    con.Open();       
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into SlideShowTable(ImageName,Description) values(@ImageName,@Description)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", fileName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", "Some Description");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();        
    BindDataList();
}
 protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadCompleteAll(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadCompleteAllEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Demo.aspx");
    Server.TransferRequest(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, false);
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Now the Problem is that on using the conventional ASP file upload control post back happens and page refreshes automatically and my data-list binds and after upload the data-list gets updated with new images. But on using the Ajax File Upload there is no post-back and no refresh happens despite the fact i have tried different things

```
Response.Redirect("~/Demo.aspx");
Server.TransferRequest(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, false);
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

but still i cant get the page to refresh and i have to manually refresh the page to get the updated Data-list on my page. Any help or solution is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Why use ajax if you are going to refresh the page anyways?

Comment: just it gave a nice look and feel... and i was trying something new but got stuck

Comment: I only ask because the purpose of Ajax is to perform task asynchronously, ie. without reloading & rendering the DOM.

Comment: so is there no way to do it..